# If I use thenCompose on a CompletableFuture and assign it do I have 2 CompletableFutures?

Tags: java, future, completable-future

Say I have a situation like the below:

```
CompletableFuture<Object1> f1 = Class1.doSomething();
CompletableFuture<Object2> f2 = Class2.doSomethingElse(f1);
boolean b = doAnotherThing(f2);
```

Where Class2 uses thenCompose() and returns with a different object type

```
CompletableFuture<Object2> doSomethingElse(CompletableFuture<Object1> f) {
return f.thenCompose(s -> {...});
```

Do I then have 2 futures? Do I need to do:

```
CompletableFuture.allOf(f1, f2);
```

How does the assignment effect the future?

Comment: where does c2 come from?

Comment: @efekctive sorry, I abbreviated it, just meant Class2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two distinct completable futures. `f1` will be completed with the `Object1` result of `doSomething`. `f2` will be completed with the `Object2` result of the anonymous function in `doSomethingElse`. However, since `f2` depends on the results of `f1`, you only need to wait on the completion of `f2` to know that both tasks are complete.

Answer (score -1):

According to java docs, thenCompose:

> Description copied from interface: CompletionStage Returns a new
>   CompletionStage that, when this stage completes normally, is executed
>   with this stage as the argument to the supplied function. See the
>   CompletionStage documentation for rules covering exceptional
>   completion.

It returns a new CompletableFuture

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-